# Select simplest element SQL Server recursion changed complexity of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have `T1` table with `Id` and `name` columns.

Table `T2` with `Aggregate_ID` and `Element_ID`.

They are crossed

x1:

```
ID и Name

1 Car
2 Hood
3 Engine
4 Cylinder 
5 Wheel
6 tyre
7 rim (car)
8 Rim fixation (Car)
```

x2:

```
Aggregate_ID Element_ID

1 2
1 3 
1 4
1 5 
3 4
5 6
5 7
7 8
```

I need to select simplest element like 2, 4, 8

Complexity and number of elements can be varied.

How can I do it with recursion?

There is another task:

I need to output all the simplest elements of which consists Wheel.

Comment: Can you give an example, this isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive solution in SQL can be very complex. In your case I see no need to use it, since it will only make your code more complex.

You can use **CTE** if you still insist:
[Recursive query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518090/recursive-query-in-sql-server)

**Non- recursive solution:**,
You want only the elements that appear in `T2` in the `Element_ID` but not in the `Aggregate_ID`:

```
SELECT Element_ID
FROM T2
EXCEPT
SELECT Aggregate_ID 
FROM T2
```

Or if you want to display all of the information for the elements:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE T1.ID NOT IN (SELECT Aggregate_ID 
                    FROM T2)
```

Comment: Big thanks. My first step was CTE but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I understood mechanism but I need more practice

Comment: You can remove all the `DISTINCT`, they are redundant.

Comment: @ypercube - `DISTINCT` sometimes used like a hint in subqueries. 1/3 isn't redundant (the first one..)

Comment: No, you are wrong. `EXCEPT` removes duplicates: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41f94/2)**

Comment: There is another task

Comment: I need to output all the simplest elements of which consists Wheel.

Comment: @ypercube -Thanks for the remark. I checked it and you are right.