# SQL Recursive match on field with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this (this is simplified)

| ID | FOO | BAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | 101 | 202 |
| 1 | 102 | 205 |
| 2 | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | 101 | 222 |
| 2 | 102 | 203 |
| 3 | 100 | 201 |
| 3 | 101 | 202 |
| 3 | 102 | 204 |
| 4 | 100 | 201 |
| 4 | 101 | 202 |
| 4 | 102 | 205 |

If i query **FOO = 100 and BAR = 200** the IDs returned are 1 and 2 that's all fine.

I would like to be able to do is **FOO = 100 and BAR = 200** and then **FOO=101 and BAR = 202** so i get returned only ID = 1

and if i did **FOO = 100 and BAR = 201** and **FOO = 101 AND BAR = 202** and **FOO = 102 and BAR = 205** i would only be returned ID 4

if i did **FOO = 100 and BAR = 201** the i would see the IDs 3 and 4

I think i should be able to do this with a recursive _CTE similar to [Recurisve query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518090/recursive-query-in-sql-server) but i cant quite get me head around how to structure it.

The levels that FOO can go too are not limited to 3 its just been simplified for this example

Comment: Could you share your query and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need common `ID`'s for every condition.

If so, and if `FOO, BAR` are unique for per `ID`, then you can do this:

```
with the_table(ID, FOO, BAR) as(
select  1 , 100 , 200 union all
select   1 , 101 , 202 union all
select   1 , 102 , 205 union all
select   2 , 100 , 200 union all
select   2 , 101 , 222 union all
select   2 , 102 , 203 union all
select   3 , 100 , 201 union all
select   3 , 101 , 202 union all
select   3 , 102 , 204 union all
select   4 , 100 , 201 union all
select   4 , 101 , 202 union all
select   4 , 102 , 205
)


select id from the_table
where
(FOO = 100 and BAR = 201) or
(FOO = 101 AND BAR = 202) or
(FOO = 102 and BAR = 205)
group by id
having count(*) = 3
```

Note that here: `count(*) = 3`, number `3` is count of conditions in `where` clause, for example if you have just one condition `(FOO = 100 and BAR = 201)`, then query is:

```
select id from the_table
where
(FOO = 100 and BAR = 201)
group by id
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this will do what i need, i wint know how many 'or' queries i will have but u will just build the query dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

No need for recursive CTE. FOR FOO = 100 and BAR = 200 and then FOO=101 and BAR = 202, you can do this.

```
with cte
as
(

SELECT ID,FOO,BAR
FROM TAB
WHERE FOO = 100 and BAR = 200
)
SELECT ID
FROM cte
WHERE FOO=101 and BAR = 202
```

For FOO = 100 and BAR = 201 and FOO = 101 AND BAR = 202 and FOO = 102 and BAR = 205, you can do this:

```
with cte
    as
    (

    SELECT ID,FOO,BAR
    FROM TAB
    WHERE FOO = 100 and BAR = 201
    )
    SELECT ID 
    FROM
    (SELECT ID,FOO,BAR
    FROM cte
    WHERE FOO=101 and BAR = 202
    ) result(ID,FOO,BAR)
    WHERE FOO=102 and BAR = 205
```

Comment: If i structure that query as <pre>;with _cte as
(
 SELECT ID
 FROM TAB
 WHERE foo = 100 AND BAR = 200
)
select * from _CTE
join TAB on TAB.id = _cte.id
WHERE TAB.foo = 101 AND TAB .bar=202</pre> it does get me part way there but i need to be able to apply a tertiary filter to the result e.g. if FOO=102  and BAR=205

Comment: You can use a nested query for that. See updated answer