# Getting Children From 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, recursion

I have two tables like this:

```
ID | Parent_Question_ID | AnswerID
```

Then another table:

```
ID | AnswerID | Sub_Question_ID
```

In here `Parent_Question_ID` and `Sub_Question_ID` are all `Question_ID`s. and `AnswerID`s are also the same.

The relationship is that a "ParentQuestion" will have 1 or more answers and answers will have one more "SubQuestion"s, which can again have 1 or more answers and so on. If a "SubQuestion" has answers it will be stored as a `Parent_Question_ID` with `Answer_ID` in table 1.

I want to write a method to get all the children of a `ParentQuestionID`. I tried several solutions but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a recursive algorithm because a Sub_Question can also have a Sub_Question.  I have do this lot of times with two column tables : 1) Parent ID 2) Child ID.

Comment: Writing the recursion has been the problem.. Since these are in 2 tables and Parent and Child Id that are different from each other

Comment: Are the two tables identical?  They should be except sorted differently.  Then you only need one table to make you recursive method.

Comment: @NatsDe Can you check if this could help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518090/recursive-query-in-sql-server

Comment: This isn't very clear. `AnswerID`s are same as what? Is the first table Questions and the second table Answers? Show some sample data. Do the answers form a chain? Do the questions form a chain or a tree? How do you know when the chain ends?