# How to retrieve all members from a transitive relationship through one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table that represents a relationship between two accounts like the following:

```
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
+---+---+
```

Columns `a` and `b` are the two sides of the relationship such that (`i`, `j`) represents a bidirectional relationship between account `i` and `j`. The preconditions for this table are the following:

- `a` will never equal `b`, i.e. `a` =/= `b`
- As the relationships are bidirectional, if there's a relationship (1, 2) there won't be another (2, 1) tuple in the table.
- Columns `a` and `b` are primary keys.

For example:

```
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | <- Will never happen
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | <- Will never happen, same as previous row
+---+---+
```

With that said, I'm implementing a feature where relationships are transitive, i.e., if there's a relationship (1, 2) and another (2, 3), then there must be an implicit relationship (1, 3).

I'm trying to find a way to do this without having to modify the schema. I would probably be able to code this doing multiple SQL queries but I don't think that would be very efficient, so I'm looking for a way to do this with  only one query that allows me for user 1, get all accounts related to them.

For example, in the first example, for account 1 I would expect the result [2, 3, 4]. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: MySQl (pre 8.0) basically has no support for hierarchical and recursive queries.  You have two options (other than changing databases).  (1) Change your data structure or (2) Use a stored procedure.

Comment: guess this is the solution for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518090/recursive-query-in-sql-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802

Comment: "I would expect the result [2, 3, 4]" meaning are "relations" are this (1, 2) , (2, 3) and (3, 4) ?