# Find all children from related subtrees with ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, hierarchy, ancestry

I have a Site Model that has_ancestry. This model hierarchy has two trees....

TREE1

SiteA (Root)

- SiteB
- SiteC

TREE2

SiteC (Root)

- SiteD

Is there a method or SQL statement to show the link between SiteA and SiteD?

Or is this not possible given they exist on separate trees (associated via SiteC)?

Comment: I don't know ancestry per say, but you can try and have a look at this question, which describes your situation in a different frame. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518090/recursive-query-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the while loop to go down to upwards and check until parent is nil.

Comment: Could you provide any preview example of how this loop would look like?

Comment: ancestry = SiteD.ancestry

This provides parent,grandparent of SiteD which is (SiteC/SiteA)